# CSS Does Not Align Div's Until Submission

Tags: html, css

On my [webpage](http://checkrepost.com/) I have a few divs and CSS classes setup to position the div's in the corners of the page. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work unless you submit a URL (You can submit `http://google.com` to test)

Why does my code only work if there was a form being submitted?

Here is my CSS:

```
.counter{
     position:absolute;
     bottom:3;
     right:3;
}
.createdby{
     position:absolute;
     bottom:3;
     left:3;
}
.changelog{
     position:absolute;
     top:3;
     right:3;
     text-align: right;
}
```

and the HTML is:

```
<div class="counter">Views: 16419</div><br>
<div class="createdby">Created by <a href="http://reddit.com/u/albuyeh">/u/Albuyeh</a> and <a href="http://reddit.com/u/aiwayume">/u/Aiwayume</a></div><br>
<div class="changelog">
Giveaways DB Last Updated: 1m 43s<br>Sweepstakes DB Last Updated: 6m 40s<br></div>
```

Comment: This is because you have `3` and not `3px`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect in at least one place.

Check this rule:

```
.changelog {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3;
    right: 3;
    text-align: right;
}
```

3 what? pixels? ems? percentage?

Comment: Your fix seems to have worked. Why would the positioning be fine after the submit though?

Comment: Because the page the form re-directs to after submit does not have those errors.

Comment: Seems like you updated your site already. Not sure my last comment is correct as it may be based on revised code.

Comment: Well both pages were using the same CSS so I am not sure why it would work after the submit.

Comment: When I checked the styles for the post-submit page, the length values had `px` units assigned. I'm not sure if that was happening before your site update (presumably it was) or why. If you want to post more info about the issue, I'll review it again.

Comment: It's fine. Issue is gone now :)

Answer (score 1):

What you've got now in your `css` is saying that the `div` should be 3 from the left. When the page opens, it doesn't know whether you mean 3 pixels, 3 feet, or 3 seconds. To fix this problem, add a unit after the number:

```
.counter{
     position:absolute;
     bottom:3px;
     right:3px;
}
.createdby{
     position:absolute;
     bottom:3px;
     left:3px;
}
.changelog{
     position:absolute;
     top:3px;
     right:3px;
     text-align: right;
}
```